# While incrementando campo datetime em MYSQL

Tags: mysql, while

Preciso fazer um while entre uma data inicial e uma data final, ou seja, enquanto a data inicial for menor que a final, retornará uma consulta, como posso incrementar esse while para faze-lo rodar?

Comment: Como assim, “retornará uma consulta”? Você quer uma tabela com todas as datas entre A e B?

Comment: Isssssso, é porque os registros são guardados usando a data como referência...então traria um registro por dia, referente as datas que correriam no while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Meu entendimento é que não existe nenhum jeito padrão de fazer isso; você precisa usar algum mecanismo proprietário do seu SGBD, e o MySQL é especialmente pobre nesse sentido. Você pode fazer uma *stored procedure*:

```
DELIMITER GO

CREATE TABLE `Calendar` (
  `Date` DATE NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY)
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE `PopulateCalendar`(`startDate` DATE, `endDate` DATE)
BEGIN
  WHILE `startDate` < `endDate` DO
    INSERT `Calendar` VALUES (`startDate`);
    SET `startDate` = DATE_ADD(`startDate`, INTERVAL 1 DAY);
  END WHILE;
END
GO

CALL `PopulateCalendar`('2015-01-01', '2024-12-31');
GO

SELECT * FROM `Calendar` WHERE `Date` BETWEEN '2015-04-01' AND '2015-04-30'
GO
```

Talvez você queira colocar índices apropriados em `Calendar` e/ou editar a `PopulateCalendar` pra não dar encrenca quando você mandar criar datas que já existem.

([SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d28c1/2))

Answer (score 0):

A resposta encontra-se nesse tópico:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13305383/how-to-loop-the-datetime-in-mysql-stored-procedure

Só encontrei após feita a pergunta.